# Apply proxy programmatically to webview in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c++11, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a webview in xaml c++ windows phone and a local running proxy on the device which I want to specify to webview...
I read that this was possible in wp7!
Is there a way or a workaround to consume the local running proxy into my webview.

Answer (score 0):

As this is answered in MSDN which is not possible. please see here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/13287270-1d49-4d23-aa89-9360673c81ef/proxy-settings-for-webview?forum=winappswithcsharp

The WebView will automatically use IE Proxy settings, that means you need to setup the IE proxy before use WebView.